# WPF ListBox - moving items up and down

Tags: wpf, vb.net, listbox

In an older WinForms app this worked, but in WPF it will move the item only once, the only current workaround is the save it to the back end DB, open again and move one more space. The list items are supplied by a DataTable

```
Private Sub Reports_BalanceSheet_ListBoxMoveUp(LB As ListBox, DT As DataTable, DisplayName As String, Optional MasterListBox As ListBox = Nothing)
    Try
        Dim StartIndex As Integer = LB.SelectedIndex
        Dim CatID As Integer = 0

        'Update the datasource
        Dim SR() As DataRow
        If DisplayName = "Name" Then
            SR = DT.Select("ID > 0 AND FormID = " & Form_ID, Nothing)
        Else
            CatID = MasterListBox.SelectedValue
            'Check that the positions are correct
            If DataChanged = False Then
                Dim vRowID As Integer = 0
                For Each Row As DataRow In DT.Rows
                    If Row("FormID") = Form_ID And Row("CatID") = CatID Then
                        Row("Position") = vRowID
                        vRowID += 1
                    End If
                Next
            End If

            SR = DT.Select("ID > 0 AND FormID = " & Form_ID & " AND CatID = " & CatID, "Position")
        End If
        Dim vString As String = ""
        Dim vUpperID As Integer = 0
        Dim vCurrentID As Integer = 0
        For Each Row As DataRow In SR
            Dim vPos As Integer = Row("Position")
            If vPos = StartIndex - 1 Then
                vUpperID = Row("ID")
            End If
            If vPos = StartIndex Then
                vCurrentID = Row("ID")
            End If
        Next
        If Not vUpperID = 0 And Not vCurrentID = 0 Then
            DT.Select("ID = " & vUpperID)(0)("Position") = StartIndex
            DT.Select("ID = " & vCurrentID)(0)("Position") = StartIndex - 1
            If DisplayName = "Name" Then
                DT.DefaultView.RowFilter = "FormID = " & Form_ID
            Else
                DT.DefaultView.RowFilter = "FormID = " & Form_ID & " AND CatID = " & CatID
            End If

            DT.DefaultView.Sort = "Position"
            DT = DT.DefaultView.ToTable
            DT.AcceptChanges()

            With LB
                .SelectedValuePath = "ID"
                .DisplayMemberPath = DisplayName
                .ItemsSource = DT.DefaultView
                .SelectedValue = vCurrentID
                .UpdateLayout()
            End With
        End If


    Catch ex As Exception
        EmailError(ex)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working this way (and with less code) :-)

```
 Dim StartIndex As Integer = LB.SelectedIndex
        Dim vTotalRows As Integer = DT.Rows.Count - 1
        If Not StartIndex = vTotalRows Then
            Dim vSelected As DataRow = DT.Rows(StartIndex)
            Dim vNew As DataRow = DT.NewRow()
            vNew.ItemArray = vSelected.ItemArray
            DT.Rows.Remove(vSelected)
            DT.Rows.InsertAt(vNew, StartIndex + 1)

            LB.SelectedIndex = StartIndex + 1

            Dim vPos As Integer = 0
            For Each Row As DataRow In DT.Rows
                Row("Position") = vPos
                vPos += 1
            Next
        End If
```